# `media9.sty' not found

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu, media9

I am using Texmaker and Gummi on Ubuntu 12.04. I want to embed videos in my PDFs and have downloaded `media9.tds.zip`, `l3kernel.tds.zip`, `l3packages.ts.zip` and `l3experimental.tds.zip`. I unzipped and pasted them in `/usr/local/share/texmf` and then I ran `sudo texhash` command in terminal.

The problem is that when I am using `media9` package in the document either using Texmaker or Gummi the error arises saying:

> LaTeX Error: File `media9.sty' not found.

I have looked for some of the answers on the similar questions but those do not work for me.

Comment: These are part of TeX Live so just use your package manager to install them in the same way you installed the rest of TeX Live.

Comment: But how can I find `media9` and these packages. The only method which I have come to know after seeing number of answers is the above that copying them and unzipping it in the `/usr/local/share/texmf`.

Comment: @cfr The version of TeXLive that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 is TeXLive2009, which doesn't have the right versions.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realise it would be that old. (TL 2011 had it for sure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It sounds like you are working off the answer from a previous question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124122/media9-installation-in-ubuntu-12-04)

This is very much the hard way to do things. I strongly recommend instead updating your whole TeXLive install, as this will remove a lot of outdated packages that cause problems. [There are a few ways detailed in this answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)
However, it APPEARS that Ubuntu has finally started shipping decently up to date versions of LaTeX. This means that it is now easier to install TeXLive, [simply install it from the backports repository, and it will update like any other package.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012) Now you don't have to install these files yourself.

Comment: Okay If I have to remove each and everything (all the packages) related to tex what is the best way to do it in Ubuntu?

Comment: @user3091054 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu

Comment: It seems there are some problems with the way I posted, the backports, so you are probably better off going with the second link and installing a 'vanilla' install.

Comment: @user3091054 You might be interested in [install-tl-ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu).

Comment: @texenthusiast Thanks for the link I removed everything accordingly.

Comment: @Canageek Thanks I have stopped that backports repository installation after reading your comment and now I am trying scottkosty method for the latest texlive distribution.. Will update you guys how it goes..

Comment: @scottkosty thanks I am giving it a try.. I will update how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how I proceeded to install Texlive 2013 and now media9 is working!

First I removed everything which had been previously installed in Ubuntu 12.04 as suggested by @texenthusiast which can be found on this link: [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu).

Secondly I downloaded the install script as suggested by @scottkosty which can be found here [Install script for TeX Live on Ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu). It actually uses the Texlive 2013  installer and there were 2775 files which had to be downloaded for the complete installation. But because of my internet connection which was disconnecting after every 20-30 minutes, the installation was restarting but it used to read the files which were installed earlier so it did not download those files but the new one. But later on the installation was stucked on file 1705 and it was not proceeding and the installation was restarting. It happened number of times with me, so I decided to download the actual texlive 2013 installer from here [Installing TeX Live over the Internet](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) to give it a try. I am sure that install script suggested by @scottskty can work for others and for me too but I did not want to remove all the files and install again from the start.

I then proceeded with the texlive 2013 installer as suggested here [TeX Live - Quick install](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). It did the same thing again read the files which were installed earlier and at reaching 1705 file it said Partial download of so and so file found removing it. So it removed the file and downloaded it again and then the installation continued and downloaded all 2775 files.

After the installation finished, I added the directory of TeX Live binaries to PATH. I did it in `/etc/profile`. I opened a terminal and wrote:

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

which opened the profile file in gedit text editor and then I added the line at the bottom and put a comment too:

```
# This path is for TEXlive2013
PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}"
```

Finally I did the things as suggested here [TeX Live and Debian/Ubuntu](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) found in the section **Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian**. This is also found in the answer suggested by @Canageek.

I really thank you all for your help in this regard.