# Video embedded into the PDF of a LaTeX beamer document as flash makes Acrobat Reader 9.4.1 crash on slide transition

Tags: pdftex, pdf, acrobat, movie15, multimedia

I have tried to embed a `.flv` video file into a PDF using either the package `flashmovie` or the package `media9` together with `beamer` and `pdfLaTeX`, as described, for instance, [here](http://abarry.org/the-complete-guide-to-embedded-videos-in-beamer-under-linux/).

The video is shown correctly in Acrobat Reader 9.4.1 on Ubuntu. However, the reader crashes when I move on to the next slide, irrespective of the contents of that slide. The reader issues the error message `(acroread:7653): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_user_time called on non-toplevel`.

Has anyone come across this problem and knows the reason/a solution?

Is the procedure described above still the recommended way of including videos into PDFs? Given that Acrobat Reader does not support flash anymore, it seems like there should be better ways.

Here is a minimal non-working example with the `flashmovie` package:

```
\RequirePackage{flashmovie} 
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{flashmovie}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \flashmovie[engine=flv-player,loop=1,width=146px,height=108px,auto=1,controlbar=0]{movie.flv} 
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is a minimal non-working example with the `media9` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}[2013/11/12]
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \includemedia[width=146px,height=108px,activate=pageopen,addresource=movie.flv,flashvars={source=movie.flv}]{alternative}{VPlayer9.swf}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different movie? Can you make a MWE?

Comment: Adobe Reader on Linux is [EOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_(product)) - use a different viewer, please.

Comment: @Martin: I would gladly use any combination of a PDF viewer and LaTeX package for videos, only I have not found any solution that works. Embedding videos in PowerPoint, Impress, etc. works like a charm. Embedding videos in LaTeX beamer does not work. I don't like the situation as it is, but it happens to be a fact. Also, installing `media9` is a joke. As long as things are [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124122/media9-installation-in-ubuntu-12-04) cumbersome, almost no one will do these things.

Comment: There is particular version of `jw-player.swf`, (don't remember where I got it from or the version number) that works much much better (smooth/robust) in 9.4.1 than any other player around. I will leave the link for a short time here, in case you want to give it a try: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/987775/player.swf (it is actually jw-player, but keep than name if you want to use it with `flashmovie` (Although `media6` works a little bit better with the text flow). See here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67663/did-anyone-succeed-in-playing-embedded-movies-inside-acrobat-in-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexander Grahn's [animate package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/animate) is a great fallback option that works beautifully when converting videos to sequences of images.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the file `flashmovie.sty`:

> ```
> There seems to be some trouble with the latex package beamer. You can't use
> the flv-player reliably with it. It is prone to crash the acrobat reader while
> changing pages.
> ```

Instead, you could try the `media9` package (`myvideo.flv` to be replaced by some file of yours):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}[2013/11/12]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Video}
  \includemedia[
    width=0.4\linewidth,height=0.3\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    addresource=myvideo.flv,        %adjust
    flashvars={source=myvideo.flv}  %adjust
  ]{\frame{Click!}}{VPlayer9.swf}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Other}
  \dots stuff
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I will go ahead and install `media9` for my `texlive` on Ubuntu (which appears to be cumbersome).

Comment: Note that you need at least `media9` version 0.34 (2013/11/12).

Comment: @Max Otherwise you could try downloading [`VPlayer9.swf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/players/APlayer9.swf) into your current directory and use an older version of `media9.sty`

Comment: Did do that. Unfortunately, I need to install some packages on which `media9.sty` depends, e.g. `expl3.sty`. This wasn't so bad if these packages were included in any Ubuntu package but I am afraid they are not.

Comment: What about installing the current TUG version TeXLive-2013. For Ubuntu, it is described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX#From_the_TeX_Users_Group

Comment: After upgrading Ubuntu, re-installing the old Acrobat reader, still having to install the most recent `l3kernel` and `l3packages` in `~/texmf`, the example you posted is compiled by `pdflatex` into a PDF. The video is shown properly in Acrobat reader, but when I move on to the next slide, the reader crashes issuing the error message `(acroread:7653): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_user_time called on non-toplevel`.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, for the good suggestions. I guess the fact that the same problem arises with `media9` makes this issue more interesting.